# Communication between SAME54 dev board and CH340

Tags: arm, serial-port, usb, mplab-x

I would like to communicate string messages between a microcontroller SAME54 and another item that has a CH340 serial adapter. I would like to connect my development board SAME54 explained with another unit that has a CH340 serial adapter.

Can I connect directly the USB serial adapter of the unit with the TARGET USB of the development board?

Do I need any other external adapter to have a successful connection?

Is there any example in MPLAB X that is able to open a serial port on the development board? How can I open the serial port from the development board?